# Service account without email address?

Tags: email, user

I want to create a couple API users (aka service accounts) for scripts that connect to Salesforce.

Is it possible to create such users that don't have email addresses?

It's extra work if I have to get more corporate email addresses created just to create extra Salesforce users for scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the user email field is always required. It doesn't *technically* have to be a real address, though, because an administrator can use the API to set the user's password. It also doesn't have to be unique; you could just as easily set it to an existing address you already have set up. The username, of course, must be unique, but also doesn't have to be a real email address (it simply needs to *look* like one).